# I have an exe setup file. I want to make it compatible with Mac OS

Tags: macos

I have an exe setup file. I want to make it compatible with Mac OS. Is there is any way through which we can convert an EXE to DMG, APP or a Jar?

Comment: So what is it that this setup.exe does exactly? You just wanna check the installed JRE version, is that it? Is the entire app in the JAR-file? I think you need to provide some more information..

Comment: Hey Oscar I have already developed a setup.exe for windows, having features like autodetecting JRE version, autoinstalling required JRE version, autostart on windows start etc. I have made this exe from a jar file(jar file was not having the above mentioned features. Features are added later when transforming a JAR to EXE. Now I was wondering if I can somehow convert exe to DMG, APP or JAR or I can add the above mentioned features in my JAR file only.) By default Mac comes with Java version 5 and my application needs minimum Java version 6 to run

Answer (score 4):

No, you cant, you need to recompile the application for the target platform.

Comment: I am also having the respective Jar file, through which I have prepared this exe. we all know that there is Java JRE inbuilt in MAC OS, I was just wondering to ask if any tool is available in the market through which we can check the Java JRE version on user PC and if the required version is not found it can automatically download the required version

Comment: You could try that Java installer. InstallAnywhere (I think).

Answer (score 2):

Nope*.

Moreover, if the contained software is compiled for Windows, it won't work on Mac.

If may work only if it is script-based (like in ruby, python, etc.). But usually, you'll have a proper Mac installation package when it is compatible.

**Exception*: some EXE are extractible archives, but it won't change the incompatibility if it is compiled for Windows.

Comment: Ok I am also having the respective Jar file, through which I have prepared this exe. we all know that there is Java JRE inbuilt in MAC OS, I was just wondering to ask if any tool is available in the market through which we can check the Java JRE version on user PC and if the required version is not found it can automatically download the required version

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is to install software on a Macintosh OS you must recompile it down to a .dmg file. I jumped on Google and this article [Creating a Mac OS X App from a Jar File](http://www.bartbusschots.ie/blog/?p=296) was the second choice. The default Mac OS Java version was 1.5 for Leopard. Target 1.4+ and you should cover systems from at least Leopard and upwards.

As an aside, [this tutorial](http://www.centerkey.com/mac/java/) was recently updated for Snow Leopard and covers the same stuff. Best of luck in getting it ported.

Answer (score 0):

There are different distribution for Mac with have java6 and below version, for java 7 and 8 you need to make another app to run and compatible with

I did it on my way:

1. **Create exe/ setup for your jar.**
2. **follow the link** ---> [winebottler.kronenberg.org](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org)
3. download winebottler(GUI based tool) for your mac type and simply follow this link below

   *https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imPGlqEuYBk*

No extra burden for you to how.

**Note**: This will pack your setup in app but app size will increase.